# while loop with rabbitmq in php

Tags: php, queue, rabbitmq

I have a trouble with rabbitmq in php.
For example

```
public function publisher(){

    $this->channel->queue_declare($this->declare, false, false, false, false);
    $msg = new AMQPMessage(test::create(['pusher'=>1]),array('delivery_mode' => AMQPMessage::DELIVERY_MODE_PERSISTENT));
    $this->channel->basic_publish($msg, '', $this->declare);
    echo " [x] Sent Pusher! \n";

    $this->channel->close();
    $this->connection->close();
}


public function subscriber(){

    $this->channel->queue_declare($this->declare, false, false, false, false);
    $callback = function($msg) {
        //echo " [x] Received ", $msg->body, "\n";
    };
    $this->channel->basic_qos(null, 1, null);
    $this->channel->basic_consume($this->declare, '', false, true, false, false, $callback);
    while(count($this->channel->callbacks)) {

        $this->channel->wait();
    }
    $this->channel->close();
    $this->connection->close();
}
```

I can run both publisher and subscriber methods via console.I add a dummy entry to test table with publisher method and then I listen to channel with subscriber.

Problem 1 :
Listening continuously it doesn't work

Problem 2 :
Process after console closed it doesn't work

things I want

1- Listening continuously
2- Working background after console closed

thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you go though tutorials 1-3 on rabbitmq? https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html

Comment: @cantSleepNow I tried them but 'while' it makes waiting on console.when I run Ctrl+c on console.it does not work